# I'm coding in R and having trouble with my if statements

Tags: r

I have a very large dataframe and I need to get the top 10 highest enrollment numbers out of the data dataframe. It is named dt and the column name of the enrollment is UGDS. The problem I'm running into is that there are NULL values for some of the colleges/universities listed so my nested if statement won't work. Also all the numbers are strings which is why I'm converting them over to integers. I have been struggling to get my nested if statement to work so I haven't put code in place to find the top 10 yet. I'm just trying to find the highest one.

Any help would be great.

```
f=dt$UGDS[1]
for(i in 2:length(dt$UGDS) {
  if(!is.null(dt$UGDS[i])) {
    if((strtoi(dt$UGDS[i])>f[1]) ==TRUE) {
      f=strtoi(dt$UGDS[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strings to numbers by using `as.integer` or `as.numeric` (depending on what your data looks like), for example (assuming you are working with integer data):

```
dt$UGDS <- as.integer(dt$UGDS)
```

Then you can get the 10 rows with the largest `UGDS`-value using:

```
head(dt[order(dt$UGDS),], n=10)
```